# Why is getBlock latest returning 0

Tags: go-ethereum

I am running geth 1.6.1 and trying to sync to ropsten testnet. When I start geth, it seems to be downloading blocks and state entries. When I run `web3.eth.syncing`,  I get `currentBlock: 986300` and is increasing every time I run. However, when I do `web3.eth.getBlock('latest').number`, it returns 0. All my account balances (web3.eth.getBalance) are also returning 0.

Command I use to start geth:

`geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"`

Comment: Could you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No, upgraded geth to 1.6.5 and still same issue

Comment: It works for me now. It seems that syncing just takes really long - several hours. I am now getting the latest block.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Although, I did fast sync and usually it only takes me few minutes. I will try again.

Comment: Well I am a complete noob here so I might be mistaken. However, I think geth is enabled on default so I am sure I had it enabled too. Yet I had to wait quite a while. I observed that `eth.hashrate` was getting larger over time and that `eth.syncing` was also changing - so if you see that behavior you really might just have to wait that long. Once it's done it shows something `Starting mining task or something`. Or write `miner.start()` into the console after running `geth console` and see what it says .. maybe it returns that it is syncing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your geth isn't synced correctly or finished syncing yet.

Please type this into your geth console:

> eth.getBlock("latest").number

You should get something equal or higher than 4,372,173
If you don't that means you need to let your geth fully sync properly.

It takes a long time to sync properly. It can be frustratingly long to sync sometimes. I have had the same issue and I let it sync for literally days before it worked properly.